# Does Star Realms support cross-platform play?

Tags: star-realms

Does the Star Realms deck-building game support cross-platform play? That is to say, if I put it on my PC or Android phone, can I play my friend on his iPad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, my account can be accessed through my Android phone or Windows PC, and I've played people on Android and iOS from both. The game is completely crossplatform.